# Bash Scipt with function / for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I'm writing a bash script for inventory information, and i'm attempting to collect data on two seperate version of Red Hat. They have two different types of output for the ifconfig, so i'm simply trying to add an 'if' statement to the already working function.  I keep getting an error that says `syntax error: unexpected end of file`
. I assume i'm not closing something somewhere, but I can't seem to see it, though i've probably been looking at it too long. any assistance would be great.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
OS_VERSION=`cat /etc/redhat-release  |awk '{print $0}'`
pat=".*Santiago.*"

num=1
        if [[ "$OS_VERSION" =~ $pat ]]; then

                for i in `/sbin/ifconfig -a |grep -i -B 3 "UP" |grep -i "HWaddr"|awk '{print $1}'`
                        do
                                {
                                MacAddress=`/sbin/ifconfig $i |grep -i -B 3 "UP" |grep -i "HWaddr"| awk '{print $NF}'`
                                Ip_Address=`/sbin/ifconfig $i|grep -i "inet addr"|awk '{print $2}'|awk -F: '{print $2}'`
                                echo -n "ethName$num=$i | ethMac$num=\"$MacAddress\" | ethIp$num=\"$Ip_Address\" | "
                                num=$(expr $num+1|bc)
                                }
                         else 
                            echo "Not Santiago, use other script"
done;
echo "";
exit
```

Comment: Try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)

Comment: `awk '{print $0}'` prints its input unchanged, did you mean `$1`?

Comment: @thatotherguy thank you sir, that helped!  It got that portion working, now I just have a bunch of other things to get working. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I see an `if`...

```
if [[ "$OS_VERSION" =~ $pat ]]; then
```

...but no `fi`. (That is the actual issue behind the error message you get -- the file ends -- unexpectedly -- before that `if` is closed.)

I see a `for` - `do` - *`else`*... followed by a `done`...?!?

It should be:

- `if` -- `then` -- [`else`] -- `fi`
- `for` -- `do` -- `done`.

You got those mixed up quite a bit. Proper indenting would have made that obvious.